# how to put selection in array?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to put selection like if else in array from while loop, Here is my codes

```
while (($importdata = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
             {
                if(($importdata[0])=='1')
                {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('sukses', ' Terdapat angka 1..');

                }
                else
                {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('sukses', ' Tidak Terdapat angka 1..');
                } }
```

I need something like

```
if (($importdata[1])=='15') { 
    do something; 
} else { 
    do something else;
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: So just add the code in the loop?

Comment: You appear to have everything you need except the courage to try it. So try it

Comment: I've add this code, but it does not work

Comment: Where did you add it

Comment: Show us what you have tried then

Comment: before this -> $data and after this -> {

Comment: No, edit your question and show us what you have tried

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: Here is your problem: `if(array($importdata[0])=='1')` you ask if an array with $importdata[0] ==1. Meaning [0 => $importdata[0] => "0"]. Remove the `array()` $importdata is already an array.

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer, but it's should be to the first flash data but it's go to second flashdata

Comment: Andreas , I'am sorry my bad, you answer is right, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, this will help you.

```
$data = [];
while (($importdata = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
  $row_count = count($importdata);
  $temp_arr = [];
  for($i = 0; $i < $row_count; $i++){
     $temp_arr['COL'.($i+1)] = $importdata[$i];
  }
   $data[] = $temp_arr;
}
```

=================Update========================

You can check conditions inside this for loop.

```
for($i = 0; $i < $row_count; $i++){
     $temp_arr['COL'.($i+1)] = $importdata[$i];
  }
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, where i can put if($importdata[0]=='1')

Comment: @AdjieSatrioPrabowo I updated answer. Do you really want to check only zeroth possition?

Comment: I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

```
while (($importdata = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
         {
            if($importdata[0]==1)
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('sukses', ' Terdapat angka 1..');

            }
            else
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('sukses', ' Tidak Terdapat angka 1..');
            } }
```